# How to detect only top edges from lines of devanarari script?

Tags: image-processing

I need to find the upper edge(upper envelop) of characters in Devanagari script for skew detection(OCR).

> The input image is like -

[image: input image of Devanagari script]

> and i would like to get output image like-

[image]

Currently, i am working in PHP.... I tried with pixel color prewitt, sobel, Laplacian of Gaussian and no success. If Hough transform used for each black pixel to find predominant lines, it could take long time to process.

Is there any idea to get the result.

Comment: If you only need the rotation of the image, you might get lucky using "image moments". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment